# MySQL: Creating and storing individual user fitness data when user is logged into their account

Tags: database-design

I'm creating a fitness related website and so currently I've created a user accounts database in MySQL, so that the user can log into their account with their username and password (login system is created with php/mysql). Now I want the user to be able to log their fitness data - example, what type of workout they did for a day and save that data so once the user logs into their account they can see their progress. Would I need to store the individual user fitness data into another mysql table? I want to connect the information via the username since it's the unique identifier for a user supposedly. Any assistance would be great, thanks!

Comment: hi, yes, perhaps create another table with a foreign key referencing the user ID, that way you can link the data to the user.

Comment: i'm pretty new to mysql, so would it make sense to use to foreign key to reference the username, or should it be the user id?